# How to make libcurl follow redirection by default?

Tags: libcurl

I'm using libnetcdf for retrieving data trought OPeNDAP protocol.

libnetcdf is using libcurl for the http transfert.

But libcurl is not following HTTP redirection. It needs CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to 1.

Is there a way to make libcurl follow redirection by default without having to edit/recompile libnetcdf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. libcurl has no default config file or anything like that.